# Rate limit a Flask API deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: api, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rate-limiting

I have created an API in Flask which uses the Flask-Limiter package to provide rate limit per remote address.

The code looks like this:

```
limiter = Limiter(
  app, key_func=get_remote_address,
  storage_uri=db_host,
  strategy="fixed-window",
)
limiter.init_app(app)
```

and then I am using the decorator in the routes I want to throttle.

The problem is that when I deploy my API to AWS elastic beanstalk it will limit requests coming from any IP as if they are the same IP.
For example, I have 1 request per minute. I hit an endpoint from IP X and after few seconds from a different IP and I am getting the 429 response code.

This is because the remote address is recognised as 127.0.0.1

How can I have rate limit for actual IP addresses that try to access my API?

My goal with throttling the API is to avoid unnecessary calls to my endpoints (let's say by bots or web scrappers).

Answer (score 0):

[Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-capture-client-ip-addresses/) passes the Remote IP Address and it can be retrieved like this for example:

```
def get_remote_address_from_elastic_beanstalk(only_first: bool = True) -> Union[str, List[str], None]:
    """ Get the client's remote ip. """
   if (request.access_route):
       if only_first:
           return request.access_route[0]
       # Return full ip list
       return request.access_route
   return None
```

And then you could use:

```
key_func=get_remote_address_from_elastic_beanstalk
```